# How do I redirect to a URL with query parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to do a redirect with query parameters, using the `redirect()` helper:

```
$link = 'https://example.com' . '?key1=value1&key2=value2';

return redirect()->to($link);
```

The problem is that when the `$link` is passed to the `to()` method Laravel removes the question mark leading the query string, so it turns this:

```
https://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

into this:

```
https://example.comkey1=value1&key2=value2
```

(again, notice the missing `?` in the final link).

How do I make a redirect with query params appended to a custom URL?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Use:

```
return redirect($link);
```

#### If you want to redirect a named route with query string, use:

```
return redirect()->route('route_name',['key'=> $value]);
```

---

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-redirect)

Comment: How you do it if you have a slug + query parameters? So example.com/{slug}?key=value ?

Comment: @Adam the same way, add `slug` and `key` parameters. Laravel knows that the parameter named `slug` goes into the URL. Anything it doesn't know from the route, goes into query parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The approved answer explains it all, according to the documentation. However, if you are still interested in finding some kind of "hard-coded" alternative:

```
$link = "https://example.com?key1={$value1}&key2={$value2}";
```

Then,

```
return redirect($link);
```

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

If the link is to a page on your domain, you don't need to re-write the domain name, just:

```
$link = "?key1=${value1}&key2=${value2}";
```

Laravel will automatically prepend the URL with your **APP_URL** (.env)

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a Single Page Application (SPA) and you want to redirect to a specific page within your app from a server request, you can use the `query` method from the `Arr` helper class. Here is an example:

```
$result = Arr::query([
    'result' => 'success',
    'code' => '200'
]);

return redirect("/purchase?$result");
```

This will redirect the user to the `/purchase` page with the query parameters `result=success and code=200`.

For example, the final url would be:

http://example.com/purchase?result=success&code=200

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the query param:

`request()->query('param')`

Redirect to a named route including query parameter:

`redirect(route('name', ['foo' => request()->query('param')]));`