# How can I get a value from the URL of a view and use it in controller?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have 2 Blade views. In the first one I send out an `id` of a `product` and *redirect* to another `view` where I need to *input* other stuff. In the *controller* I can't get the `id` from the first view in order to use it to **store** all the information from both views in my database.

I need to get the `shoe_id/$product->id` value!

Here is the first view:

```html
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" required/>
    <button class ="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</h3>
@if($products->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <form action="sell/{{$product->id}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                {{-- <a href="{{'products/sell/' . $product->id }}"> --}}
            <button name="shoe_id" value="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn">
                <img src="/imagini/{{ $product->id }}.1.jpg" style="height: 210px">
            </button>
                {{-- </a> --}}
            </form>
            <p style="text-align: center">{{ $product->title }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Here is the second view:

```html
<form action="/select/{product_id}" method="post">
    @csrf

    <h2>Select a size:</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
        <select class="select2" name="size" style="width: 300px">
            <option>35</option>
            <option>35.5</option>
            <option>36</option>
            <option>36.5</option>
            <option>37</option>
            <option>37.5</option>
            <option>38</option>
            <option>38.5</option>
            <option>39</option>
            <option>39.5</option>
            <option>40</option>
            <option>40.5</option>
            <option>41</option>
            <option>41.5</option>
            <option>42</option>
            <option>42.5</option>
            <option>43</option>
            <option>43.5</option>
            <option>44</option>
            <option>44.5</option>
            <option>45</option>
            <option>45.5</option>
            <option>46</option>
            <option>46.5</option>
            <option>47</option>
            <option>47.5</option>
            <option>48</option>
            <option>48.5</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
        <h2>Insert the price:</h2>
        <input type="text" style="width: 300px" placeholder="$" name="price" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg px-3" value="Sell!">
</form>
```

Here is the controller:

```php
public function store($shoe_id){
    request()->validate(['price'=> 'required|max:255']);

    // $url = request('id');

    dd($shoe_id);

    ListedProducts::create([
        'user_id'=> auth()->id(),
        // 'shoe_id'=> ,
        'size'=>request('size'),
        'price'=>request('price')
    ]);

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

And the web.php file:

```php
Route::post('sell/{product_id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'sell'])->name('sell');
Route::get('sell/{product_id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('select',[App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'store']);
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is just to use query params for HTTP GET.

When redirecting to `/home` add the query param `shoe_id`

```php
return redirect()->route('home', ['shoe_id' => $shoe_id]);
```

Then in your `home` controller function, get the `shoe_id` query param with

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    $shoe_id = $request->input('shoe_id');
    
    ...

}
```

Edit: please read this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542354/how-do-i-redirect-to-a-url-with-query-parameters/48542421).

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way you could accomplish the same thing:

```
return redirect("home?shoe_id={shoe_id}");
```

then in the index method you could do the same thing as @Ezra suggested:

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
    $shoe_id = $request->input('shoe_id');
    
    ...

}
```